# Content card with link to product page

Tags: html, hyperlink, card

I'm building a site for my store, and I want to make cards that are clickable and lead to the product. Could you help me to compose that part of the code? I am using HTML, SCSS and JS

```
<li>
    <h2>
        <div class="slider">
            <img src="img/Products/wheat/almond.png" class="product" width="180" />
        <div class="desc">Борошно Мигдальне 250гр</div>
        <div class="price">128 грн</div>
    </h2>
</li>
```

this would be the cards, I want them to be totally clickable
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUUdC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What you could be searching is "href" try something like this in youre HTML: `href="/Card"`. To get the Click Sign you can add `cursor: pointer;` in your CSS.